# How to use only automatically build RAID arrays on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, mdadm, initramfs, initrd

I have an Ubuntu 16.06 system where `/` on an SSD primary partition and `/home` with md RAID0 on four SSD devices. The file `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` is automatically generated by `mkconf` and contains no devices nor arrays. I have `UUID=<uuid for fs> /home ext4 defaults` in `/etc/fstab` and that is enough to assemble the RAID. The system boots fine, correctly assembles the RAID and mounts it as expected. However, after upgrading packages `update-initramfs` always emits a warning

```
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
```

How can I keep using the fully automatic RAID assembly with only `/etc/fstab` containing the file system UUID for `/home` and avoid the warning message from `update-initramfs`?

Answer (score 0):

Update your initramfs as outlined in the manual by copying the mdadm.conf into /etc/update-initramfs/etc folder (not tested, it may have to be an mdadm subfolder).

Comment: I don't agree with this solution. After digging around in the filesystem I found that warning is emitted by `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mdadm`. There's a simple `grep -q '^ARRAY'` against current mdadm configuration and warning message will be emitted if the above regexp does not match at least once. The system works fine with that so I opted to change `warn` to `info` in that file and just forget about the issue.

Comment: That would work as well.